# PHP select and save text template

Tags: php, html

im new to php/html and i don't even know if PHP has ability like that. 
What i want to do is to select some text from input and save it to txt file.
I have a for which takes all text from it and saves to .txt file. But there is alot of not necessary text and it makes .txt file big and hardly readable.
This is what text i usually paste

```
# userid name                uniqueid            connected ping loss state
#    122 "bryerzavala"       [U:1:167845174]     03:25      152    0 active
#    118 "zhabka"            [U:1:12080791]      05:41      109    0 active
```

and the part i need is only [U:1:167845174] so it would be great is there is an way to make a non needed text trown away and the file save only [U:X:XXXXXXXXX] part.

Comment: You would need a form to submit the data then capture what you need and save to txt file. All with php

Comment: Why dont you use a database such as mysql?

Answer (score 2):

There are some options to do what you want, it all depends on how the input text is formatted:

1. If the input text is always formatted the same way for every line, meaning uniqueid is going to be located in the same position you could use `substr` http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
2. If the position of uniqueid varies on every line you could use a regular expression to extract the part of the text line you are looking for, in this case you could use `preg_match` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

**here is a simple approach. may be you will like it**

i'll use the example of file.txt you have provided to simulate the input data.

**old.txt**

```
# userid name                uniqueid            connected ping loss state
#    122 "bryerzavala"       [U:1:167845174]     03:25      152    0 active
#    118 "zhabka"            [U:1:12080791]      05:41      109    0 active
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('./test.txt', true);

// var_dump($file);//for debug
preg_match_all('/\[U:\d:\d+\]/',
    $file,
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

var_dump($out); //for debug


//save data in your file 
$fp = fopen("incomming.txt", "w");

foreach ($out[0] as $key => $data) {
    fwrite($fp, $data.PHP_EOL);
}
//close file
fclose($fp);


echo '<hr/>';
$lines = file('incomming.txt');
var_dump($lines);
```